# Initiating call and receiving call in web browser using freeswitch

Tags: sip, freeswitch, mod-verto, pjsua2

I have a  requirement, i have a web site in which i want to implement outgoing call and incoming call functionality. I am using freeswitch on windows as sip server, currently i am able to initiate call on local extensions using verto, how can i  initiate outbound calls to mobile phone directly from browser and also able to receive the calls using browser.

Answer (score 3):

Freeswitch has webrtc support, which means you can use **SIP-webRTC** client to register from browser and do IN/OUT calls.

1. **SIP-webRTC** client
   Open source libs like JsSIP, sipJS, sipml5
2. **SIP-Flash** client 
   red5, flash phoner.

Paid libs which support both is [Plivo](https://www.plivo.com),[Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/client/sip-to-webrtc) websdk.