# How to implement a click to dial from my website

Tags: freeswitch

First off I should be up front that my level of knowledge is currently zero so I am doing as much research as I can for myself and have the books to hand.

I've read through the following article as I believe it relates to my question https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/XML+Dialplan

My research leads me to believe I am required to create a dial lpan to initiate two phone calls, one to the users extension number and one to the external phone and then bridge these two calls together. The freeswitch server will have multiple domains and share the same extensions across the domains. I will have at the time of the 'click to call' all the information about the user, his domain and the phone on his desk.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this functionality. I hope I have the right idea but potentially click to call doesn't even work the way I think it does.

I appreciate this may actually be impossible to answer with the info I have provided but I don't yet know that or I genuinely have my approach completely back to front.

Here's hoping someone has a dial plan I can cut and paste and replace some variables and voila. But that is probably wishful thinking.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105632/initiating-call-and-receiving-call-in-web-browser-using-freeswitch/41117397

Comment: In the end this was resolved by calling a LUA script over the network. The LUA script is handling making both calls and bridging them. Also making use of NEventSocket to connect to fs_cli to execute the luarun command.